# Face Detection is Not Working iPhone X Portrait in FirebaseMLVision?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have use the google api for face detection. so i have integrate via firebase also installed framework from firebase.

> Face Detection is working fine in iPhonex when device is in landscape
>   mode.
>
> But when device is in Portrait mode it's not working.

I have debug and found that in `FirebaseMLVision.framework` have `processImage` method in which passing the image, but Result is always blank when device is in Portrait.

**Method FirebaseMLVision.framework**

```
- (void)processImage:(FIRVisionImage *)image
          completion:(FIRVisionFaceDetectionCallback)completion
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(process(_:completion:));
```

**I called as below:**

```
[_faceRecognizer
     processImage:image
     completion:^(NSArray<FIRVisionFace *> *faces, NSError *error) {
         if (error != nil || faces == nil) {
             completed(emptyResult);
         } else {
             completed([self processFaces:faces]);
         }
     }];
```

Please help me what is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: If you think the SDK is not operating correctly, file a bug report with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Okay, Send report.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried out the QuickStart mlvision sample app? Its face detection should work fine in iPhone X portrait mode.

Comment: Here is the link to the QuickStart mlvision sample app: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlvision

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was solved.
The image passed to MLKit seems to fail to be detected if the vertical length exceeds 1280.

If you are using `AVCaptureSession`, try changing the value of `sessionPreset`.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
```

By fixing the resolution of the output image at 720x1280, the face is detected normally.

If you are not using AVCaptureSession, try changing the image resolution.